# How to remove records simultaneously?

Tags: spring-mvc, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

**Case:** in a package I have a class that Performs activirt for patients & doctors

- Patient specifict operations( `post`, `get`, `put`, `delete`) are done by  `Patient` controller,
- Doctor specifict operations( `post`, `get`, `put`, `delete` ) are done by  `Doctor` controller

There are:

- 4 doctors: A, B, C and D;
- 50 patients - one of them with name Z
- one doctor have multiple patients
- one patient can consult multiple doctors

Patient Z consults doctors A, B & D.

**Question:** How to, upon deletion of patient, remove it from each of the doctors he attends, and upon deletion of doctor, remove it from patients who attended him?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly , this is what you want to do

Doctor A attended patients x, y, z…
Doctor B attended patients x, y, z…
Doctor C attended patients x, y, k…  ( doctor C did not attended patient z).
Doctor D attended patients x, y, z…

Now you are looking  in to the list of patients attended by doctor A, and you deleted patient z from this list. So , the patient z should get deleted from list of doctor B and D. You want model the data for Cassandra database.

We need to remember the goals while modelling Cassandra schema.

First goal– Know your Query data.
Second goal – Try to distribute data across the cluster.
Third goal – Minimise the number partition reads.

Our queries would be  - 
1 – Get all the patients attended by Doctor A  (B,C,D).
2 – Delete the patient history (from any list).

Let’s give a try -

```
CREATE TABLE VISITS_BY_DOCTOR(
 Doctor_name  text ,
 Patient_name  text ,
 .
 .
 .
 Other columns 

 PRIMARY KEY (Doctor_name, Patient_name    )
)
```

This will satisfy our two goals. First goal, in one query we can get the list of patients attended by doctor A. 
Select * from VISITS_BY_DOCTOR where Doctor_name = A;
Delete from VISITS_BY_DOCTOR where patient_name = z;

Second goal , it also minimize the number of partition reads as we can get data based on partition key “doctor_name”. But this design do not satisfy third goal, spread data across the cluster. So let’s improve it.

```
CREATE TABLE VISITS_BY_DOCTOR(
Doctor_name  text ,
Patient_name  text ,
Visit_date bigint,
.
Other columns 

PRIMARY KEY ((Doctor_name, Patient_name), Visit_date    )
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (Visit_date    DESC).
```

This will satisfy the “spread data across the cluster” goal. Also it can be used to get history based on visiting date.

Comment: I am guessing even this can spread data across cluster ((PRIMARY KEY (Doctor_name, Patient_name)) i.e. without adding the Visit_date. Do you agree?

Comment: Also, you can't do this Delete from VISITS_BY_DOCTOR where patient_name = z; as it misses parition key